# 500 error when I try to go to my GitHub profile

Tags: github

When I go to my profile https://github.com/rfsan I get a 500 error, but if I try incognito mode there is no problem. Do you know what is possibly going on?

Answer (score 1):

Clear your cookies, and log in again. There is likely some browser cookie state thing that is making github error out. [500 error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_server_errors) means "internal server side error". It generally pretty embarassing for a company to have something like this. Especially the size of github.

Comment: I used Control+F5 and it worked. No need to log in again.